# laravel7 override vendor package class

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm new to this service container stuff in general.

Just looking for an easy way to override the [getView()](https://github.com/igoshev/laravel-captcha/blob/master/src/Captcha/Captcha.php#L105) method of the `Captcha` class.

My idea was to create a new class extending the `captcha` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Helpers\Captcha;

use Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha\Storage\StorageInterface;
use Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha\Generator\GeneratorInterface;
use Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha\Code\CodeInterface;

class CaptchaNew extends Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha
{
    /**
     * Get html image tag.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function getView()
    {
        //new code...
    }
}
```

Inside the `AppServiceProvider` under `register` method using:

```
    $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();

    $loader->alias('App\Http\Helpers\Captcha\CaptchaNew', 'Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha');
```

I already tried the `boot` method too, doesn't work too. What's the best way to override the class? A `serviceProvider' is provided too, but I want to keep things simple and I have no idea about serviceProviders in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way below to register your service, use bind function instead. 
Under your `register` function in AppServiceProvider, replace yours with the sample code below. But please be noticed that first parameter of bind function must be same as facade accessor of vendor library (in this case is \Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha\Captcha::class, you can take a look [here](https://github.com/igoshev/laravel-captcha/blob/master/src/Facades/Captcha.php)). Register this facade in config/app.php after the service provider of package:

```
$this->app->bind(\Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha\Captcha::class, function(){
     return new CaptchaNew($this->app['config']);
})
```

Comment: it says `Argument 1 passed to Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha\Captcha::__construct() must be an instance of Igoshev\Captcha\Captcha\Code\CodeInterface, instance of Illuminate\Config\Repository given` how to pass now the correct config?